# Fourier sums convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am given the Sin series expansion:
(1)$$x=2\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}Sin(nx)$$

But how do I deal with a solution given by:
(2)$$S(x)=\sum_{2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{n^{3}}{n^{4}+1}Sin(nx)$$

However, as can be seen, the above series converges poorly; like 1/n

I need to get the above Sin series expansion(2) into the form 
$$S(x)=\frac{-x}{2}|periodic extension +\frac{Sin(x)}{2}-\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n(n^{4}+1)}Sin(nx)$$

Been looking at this for a couple of hours but couldn't figure out how to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is simply $\frac{n^3}{n^4+1}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n(n^4+1)}$.

Comment: I know that.
But the challenge is the index. Notice that the sum commences at different n.

Comment: What is the value of $\frac{n^3}{n^4+1}$ when $n=1$? You already accounted for that with your $\frac{\sin x}{2}$ in your third equation.

Comment: It's 1/2. 
The third equation is what I am required to arrive at from (1) and (2).

Comment: I am just saying $\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{n^3}{n^4+1}g_n(x) = -\frac{g_1(x)}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{g_n(x)}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}g_n(x)/(n+n^5).$ Take $g_n(x)$ as $(-1)^n\sin(nx)$.

Comment: Is $$n(n^{4}+1)$$ supposed to be in the denominator?

Edit: saw your edit

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio This is hopeless. I'm not understanding it. Especially the part where the index shift to 1

Comment: And the part where $$\frac{sin(x){2}$$ appears

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio 
You might have to show me the detailed steps. I'm very terrible with summations and index.